# how to change permissions of .gvfs in my home folder

Tags: permissions, gvfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File permissions: why  can't I list a directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42411/file-permissions-why-cant-i-list-a-directory)

my home folder has a listing for.gvfs like this

```
d?????????  ? ?             ?                 ?                ? .gvfs/
```

How do I change that permission? 
chmod and chown does not seem to work!
gives me permission denied error

```
chown: cannot access `.gvfs': Permission denied
```

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42411/file-permissions-why-cant-i-list-a-directory

Comment: That's not a problem of a missing +x permission, it's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gvfs/+bug/225361).